# Why am I getting a value error when I call random integer?

Tags: python

I am writing a program where you input a phrase like, "hear me" and it outputs an anagram phrase. Example: "hem ear". I have been having an issue with t= a function I wrote, called FindRandomWordofLength. I keep getting a value error when I call randint. I have isolated the problem by creating a script called, test_random_word. Can anyone explain the source of this error?

```
import random

def CreateDictionary(text):
    """
    :param text: A txt file of English words, one word per line.
    :return: Dictionary with keys: "2", "3", "4", ..."12" denoting the length of the words, and values are lists of
    words with the appropriate length.
    """
    dict = {"2": [], "3": [], "4": [], "5": [], "6": [], "7": [], "8": [], "9": [], "10": [], "11": [], "12": []}
    with open(text, "r") as fileObject:
        for line in fileObject:
            if 1 < len(line.strip()) < 12:
                dict[str(len(line.strip()))].append(line.strip())

    return dict


def FindRandonmWordofLength(dict, length):
    """
    :param dict: a dictionary constructed from the CreateDictionary function.
    :param length: an integer value between 3 and 12, including endpoints.
    :return: a random word from the dictionary of the requested length.
    """
    length_of_list = len(dict[str(length)])
    random_num = random.randint(1, length_of_list - 1)
    return dict[str(length)][random_num]

dict = CreateDictionary("20k.txt")

for i in range(1000000):
    random_length = random.randint(3, 12)
    word = FindRandonmWordofLength(dict, random_length)

    print("The random word is: " + word)
```

I see this error a lot.

> return self.randrange(a, b+1)   File
>   "C:\Users\kevoh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\random.py",
>   line 200, in randrange
>       raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width)) ValueError: empty range for randrange() (1,0,
>   -1)

Comment: error message should also show you which line of your code makes problem - not only which line in standard module makes problem.

Comment: lists in Python are numbered at zero, not one - so if you use `randint(1, length_of_list - 1)` then you can get randint(1,1) which can make empty range as you can see in message. If you want to get random element from list then module `random` has better functions for this - like `random.choice()`

Comment: print - `length_of_list = len(dict[str(length)])` length maybe have a `0` value 0 - 1 = -1 You should handle it

Comment: @furas ++ for `random.choice()`. Although `randint` is inclusive on both ends, so `randint(1, 1)` returns 1. The error seems to be stemming from `randint(1, 0)`...

Answer (score 1):

When using `random.randint(a, b)`, you must ensure that `a <= b`, otherwise that error `empty range for randrange()` will result. My best guess here is that you aren't double-checking that you're passing valid parameters into your call to `random.randint()`. For one, if `length_of_list == 1`, then you just called `random.randint(1, 0)`, which will give exactly the error message you got. Perhaps you could try `random_num = random.randint(0, length_of_list - 1)`, since python list indices start at 0, avoiding this problem.

If your intended behavior is to get a random integer at an interval starting at 1 (which doesn't seem to be the case here), adjust the second parameter accordingly.